# Expanding copy last column with data to next blank column code to include converting formulas to values

Tags: vba, excel

Will just preface this by saying that my VBA skill is pretty much limited to tweaking existing code - to keep it brief, essentially I have the following code...

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim LastCol As Integer

Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

LastCol = rLastCell.Column

ws.Columns(LastCol).Copy ws.Columns(LastCol + 1)

End Sub
```

...which copies the last column with data, to the next column with no data. My workbook is essentially going to be a 'master' spreadsheet that pulls and records a column of data from a report that's generated daily (data.xls), using the following function:

```
=VLOOKUP("Sheet1",data.xls!$A$2:$B$40,2, FALSE)
```

The problem I've encountered is that when data.xls changes the next day, when I update the workbook, the record from the previous day changes too.

My only potential solution so far is to somehow use VBA to copy the last column with the formulas across to the next blank column, which the above code achieves, but then also convert the column that was copied to values.

I've tried to incorporate code that converts *all* formulas to values but if it runs before the copy, it copies the values instead of formulas--and if it runs *after* the copy, the formula is lost completely.

Is there any way I can target not the last column with data, but the column *before* the last column with data and convert it to values?

Comment: Add this after the Copy line: `ws.Columns(LastCol).Value = ws.Columns(LastCol).Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'...
LastCol = rLastCell.Column

With ws.Columns(LastCol)
    .Copy .Offset(0,1)
    .Value = .Value
End with
```